# Attempting to reference a deleted function.

Tags: c++

I am having difficulty with my code. I am getting the error "AssociativeArray>::Node::Node(void)': attempting to reference a deleted function"

Here is my class

```
template<typename K, typename V>
class AssociativeArray
{
  public:
    AssociativeArray(int = 2);  // default constructor of a capacity of 2
    AssociativeArray(){ delete [] data; }
    AssociativeArray(const AssociativeArray<K,V>&); 
    AssociativeArray<K,V>& operator=(const AssociativeArray<K,V>&);
    V& operator[](const K&); // getter
    V operator[](const K&) const;  // setter
    queue<K> keys() const;
    int size() const {return siz;};
    bool containsKey(const K&) const;
    void deleteKey(const K&);
    void clear();

  private: 
    int cap;
    int siz;
    int values;
    void capacity(int);
    struct Node{K key; V value; bool inUse;};
    Node* data;  // data = new Node[cap]
    void ExpandNode(int,int);
};
```

Here is the constructor which is giving me the problem.

```
template<typename K, typename V>
AssociativeArray<K, V>::AssociativeArray(int cap)
{
  this->cap = cap;
  this->siz = 0;

  data = new Node[cap];  // ERRORS HERE

  for (int index = 0; index < cap; index++)
  {
    data[index].inUse = false;
  }
}
```

Here is the declaration in main.

```
AssociativeArray<string, AssociativeArray<string, bool>> seen(10);
```

Comment: Why does your second constructor delete the array? Should that not be the destructor?

Comment: I completely missed that, it is supposed to be the destructor.

Comment: @silverscania the ~ key must have malfunctioned, you're right!! on some keyboards you have to type it + next char or it doesn't appear. Annoying.

Comment: @silverscania That solved it, thank you.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: International keyboard layouts; it's a dead key for ã etc. Windows tip: Set up a US-international alternate keyboard layout, and switch with right-shift-alt.

Comment: @MSalters and I'm not even spanish ;) I've no use for that piñata stuff when programming. thanks. I don't like right shift alt because it used to switch the keyboard on xemacs all the time when replacing stuff..;

Answer (score 1):

The `Node` class' default constructor is used for each item when you create a raw array of `Node`.

For some reason there is no such default constructor. Presumably the `Key` member lacks a default constructor. However, you're not showing the code so this about reasons is just speculation.

One good way to create an array without invoking the default constructor for the item type, is to use a `std::vector`. Alternatively, if it is meaningful to do so then you can just define a default constructor. But using a `std::vector` also deals with a host of other problems, so I recommend that you do that regardless.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I forgot to mention I was not allowed to use a vector. But yes, that would have been better.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was there was no destructor. I forgot to add the ~ in front of "AssociativeArray(){ delete [] data; }" Thus I suspect I had 2 constructors and it was calling the constructor that deleted the data array.